# Múltiplo de um número em C

Tags: c

eu estou fazendo um algoritmo que encontra o primeiro múltiplo de 11, 13 ou 17, mas não sei como eu faço para mostrar apenas o primeiro múltiplo dentro de um laço de repetição.

```
int numero;

printf("Digite um numero : ");
scanf("%d",&numero);

for (int contador = 1; contador <= numero; contador++){
    if (contador % 11 == 0 || contador % 13 == 0 || contador % 17 == 0){
        printf("%d \n",contador);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você deseja é o MMC - Mínimo Múltiplo Comum dos três números.

Por definição:
- mmc(x,y) = (x * y) / mdc(x,y)
- mmc(x, mmc(y, z)) = mmc(mmc(x, y), z)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mdc(int x, int y) {
    /* Cálculo do mdc(x,y) utilizando o algoritmo de Euclides */
    if (x < y) {
        return mdc(y, x);
    }
    else {
        if (x % y == 0)
            return y;
        else
            return mdc(y, x%y);
    }

}

int main() {
    int n1, n2, n3, a, b, mmc;
    printf("Informe os 3 números: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3);
    a = mdc(n1, n2);
    b = mdc(a, n3);
    mmc = (n1 * n2 * n3)/ b;
    printf("\nO MDC de %d , %d e %d é : %d\n", n1, n2, n3, mdc);
    printf("\nO MMC de %d , %d e %d é : %d\n", n1, n2, n3, mmc);
    return 0;
}
```

Em relação à sua tentativa você tem que fazer:

```
contador = 1;
while (contador <= (11 * 13 * 17)) {
    if (contador % 11 == 0 && contador % 13 == 0 && contador % 17 == 0){
        printf("%d \n",contador);
        break; /* interromper o loop quando encontrar o mmc*/
     }
    contador++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como sua pergunta é sobre como mostrar somente o primeiro resultado e não sobre o algoritmo em sí, isso é bem básico, é só botar um break:

```
int numero;

printf("Digite um numero : ");
scanf("%d",&numero);

for (int contador = 1; contador <= numero; contador++){
    if (contador % 11 == 0 || contador % 13 == 0 || contador % 17 == 0){
        printf("%d \n",contador);
        break;  <============================
    }
}
```